# Write contents of array to a text file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to write the contents of an array to a text file in my iPhone application. I can load the array from the text file but i want to allow deleting of content through the array and again write the contents to the text file. How can I achieve this? Or simply if anyone can guide me how to delete the last word of a text file would also be helpful.
**EDIT :-** basically i want to delete the last word in a text file. can you help me with the logic to achieve that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the approach in other answers works bu the file is written in a XML format. to simply write the contents of the array in a text file , I first Appended all the strings of the array into a large string then write that string into the text file .below is the code i used for that

```
NSString *stringToWrite=[[NSString alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<[stringArray count]; i++)

{
stringToWrite=[stringToWrite stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[stringArray objectAtIndex:i]]];

}

[stringToWrite writeToFile:textFilePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

this will write the contents of the array in plain text format.

Answer (score 4):

Write the contents of your original array as shown below:

```
[firstArray writeToFile:@"/Users/sample/Untitled.txt" atomically:YES];
```

Whenever you want to retrieve and modify the array, retrieve the contents of the file int an NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *myArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/sample/Untitled.txt"];
[myArr removeLastObject];  //Any modification you wanna do
[myArr writeToFile:@"/Users/sample/Untitled.txt" atomically:YES];
```

Comment: its stored in this format `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
 <string>one</string>
 <string>two</string>
 <string>three</string>
 <string></string>
</array>
</plist>
 `

Comment: @Bonnie, the format is OK, the other method in the answer reads it back in as an array of strings. Unless you need the file to be in a particular format?

Comment: @jrturton , i need it to be in plain text format, for using it further, basically i want to delete the last word in a text file. can you help me achieve that

Answer (score 2):

There is method in `NSArray` to write the array into a file.

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

Please check the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Comment: thanks that helped a little but the array is written in xml format here's how it is saved <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"><br/>
<br><plist version="1.0"><br/>
<br><array>
 <string>one</string><br/>
 <string>two</string>
 <string>three</string>
 <string></string>
</array>
</plist>
i only want the string to be written, will i have to use an xml parser ? its much more trouble, is there a workaround ?