# Write contents of NSMutableArray to a text file in iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I referred following links but its not working in iOS 8.3 iPod

[Write contents of array to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754194/write-contents-of-array-to-a-text-file)

[is it possible to save NSMutableArray or NSDictionary data as file in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829631/is-it-possible-to-save-nsmutablearray-or-nsdictionary-data-as-file-in-ios)

```
NSString *file_path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/app_name/untitled.txt"];
[myArr writeToFile:file_path atomically:YES];
```

I am trying to write NSMutableArray in text file. This code is not working for iOS 8.3, where NSMutableArray has NSMutableDictionary contents.

Comment: 'Not working' in what sense? What output do you get?

Comment: @Tommy file is not created in application's local folder. Instead of NSMutableArray, if i use NSString like [string writeToFile:file_path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; file is created.

Comment: So what is `file_path` set to?